# How to run crosswalk-app for android application in Mac OS

Tags: android, crosswalk

I am using Mac OS to developer android application and want to user crosswalk in my application. I followed the instruction from https://crosswalk-project.org/documentation/android/system_setup.html#Android but it seems that crosswalk only support Windows & Linux. Is there a way to use it in Mac OS? Below is the error I got when run `crosswalk-app check android`

```
+ Checking host setup for target android
*** ERROR: Checking for android... null
  + Checking for ant... /Users/tools/apache-ant-1.9.7/bin/ant
  + Checking for java... /usr/bin/java
*** ERROR: Checking for lzma... null
  + Checking for ANDROID_HOME... /Users/Library/Android/sdk/
```

It shows error on checking for android. I already downloaded android sdk and android studio but it still not able to recognise it.

Answer (score 1):

After some searching and got solution:  I need to add this path on PATH environment: $ANDROID_HOME/tools

Crosswalk android is using android script which is under $ANDROID_HOME/tools directory,  to manage android app project.